# Issue with spacing between items in twitter bootstrap theme

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I had a fixed width container right below the heading text that holds a slider on the page and as soon as I made it a fluid container so it could span the width of the page it ended up moving down quite a bit.

I have tried adding pixels in margin-top and padding-top for the fluid-container although it doesn't seem to move it back up.

I cant seem to figure out how remove the space and hope someone can help.

**EDIT:** Here is a link to the page http://goo.gl/8JUDA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite some elements above the slider box that don't show any content, but contribute to the space. The most is added by the `padding:40px 0 0 0;` of the `.hero-unit` and `padding-bottom:40px` of the `.homepage` classes, but you also have some paragraph containers, that also may add some space.

However ... the padding parameters push the **relative positioned** container down.
Look for them in the file:

http://development.ugamer.tv/wp-content/themes/rachelbaker-bootstrapwp-Twitter-Bootstrap-for-WordPress-9bc2021/style.css

Fixing these should work.

---

Also ... this is a broken link:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='ugamer-css'  href='http://development.ugamer.tv/wp-content/themes/rachelbaker-bootstrapwp-Twitter-Bootstrap-for-WordPress-9bc2021style.css?ver=0.90' type='text/css' media='all' />
```